# How to create a macro: let a button use a cell value

Tags: excel, command, vba

I have a list with asset tags in excel. I have 2 columns (F and G). In G are the actual asset tags. In F I would like to create a button on every row that executes a macro using the data in the cell next to it in column G

Example of Columns:

[image: Example of Columns]

I have a little bit of VBA code that starts vncviewer.exe with the asset tag in column G. It's a nice bit of code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
       'Call Shell("c:\progra~1\realvnc\vncvie~1\vncviewer.exe " & Target.Value)
    Call Shell("c:\progra~1\realvnc\vncvie~1\vncviewer.exe " & Target.Value)
End If
End Sub
```

But you have to double click on the cell in column G to enter the data in the cell and then hit Enter or Tab to get out of it. This activates the vncviewer successfully.

I would like the macro to take over this double-click and exiting of the cell next to the button I click on.

The (recorded) Macro below seems to do what I want (except for only entering G2, copying pasting in place and exiting to H2), but I have no idea how to make it so that I can make an individual button on each row in Column F corresponding the asset tag next to it in G

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("H2").Select
End Sub
```

This is a screenshot of the button creation:

[image: This is a screenshot of the button creation]

Comment: You could start by recording a macro while adding a button and then taking it from there. If you get stuck, post the code and somebody will finish it off for you.

Comment: Thanks SJR. The Sub Macro2() is actually a recorded macro. But it is logically stuck on 1 cell. I just don't have the knowledge yet to go on :)

Comment: OK, but it doesn't make a button. What are these buttons for?

Comment: True... I created a button (form Control) in Developer mode in Excel and assigned the Macro2 to it.

Comment: I don't know that you can get exactly what you want.  Button controls are VBA objects, not table objects.  They don't have "cell" locations.  In other words, you don't have a button in G2 or H2 - you might have one "over" it, but not IN it.

Comment: So what is the endgame here. You want a button to appear in F whenever G is changed and does each button run the same macro or a different one? @Jaberwocky - yes, I think it means over it.

Comment: It seems to me he wants a button for each row that runs using the contents of that row.  But he believes buttons are associated to rows automatically by what cell they are over; which is false.

Comment: Yes, but you can relate buttons to cells using the Top etc properties.

Comment: I have a dummy workaround. Create 100 macro's and assign each button to a macro, but that is crazy.

Would be like:
    Sub Macro2()
    '
    ' Macro2 Macro
    '

    '
        Range("G2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("H2").Select
    End Sub

    Sub Macro3()
    '
    ' Macro3 Macro
    '

    '
        Range("G3").Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("H3").Select
    End Sub


etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, your column G is just a list.  You don't necessarily want to invoke VNCViewer when the list is changed but, instead, you would like the user to be able to select one of those values and then click a button to get VNCViewer to use its value.

If so, try this (assuming your button is linked to the `Macro2` subroutine):

```
Sub Macro2()
    If Selection.Column = 7 Then
        Shell "c:\progra~1\realvnc\vncvie~1\vncviewer.exe " & Selection.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

and delete your `Worksheet_Change` code.

The user will then be able to simply select a cell in column G by clicking it, then click the single button.

Comment: PERFECT! This works for me. Just select a cell and press the button and VNC starts! THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're after, but this might start you off

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim b As Button

    Call Shell("c:\progra~1\realvnc\vncvie~1\vncviewer.exe " & Target.Value)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(Target.Offset(, -1).Left, Target.Top, Target.Width, Target.Height)
    With b
        '.OnAction = "btnS"
        .Caption = "Btn " & target.row
        .Name = "Btn" & target.row
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What your script seems to do is generate a button in the cell left (col F) of the asset number (col G). This button does not do anything after that.

What I need is a button or any other trigger that takes care of the VBA script in my first part of the text. Like select and drag down (the Cross symbol in excel). So I can use the button on the specific line to start Vncviewer for the asset tag behind it.